# Call sent to two reciever with different userId

Tags: ios, swift, sinch

We are using the sinch SDK (ios and android). We are using the phone number as identifier. We are using the sandbox host.
A, B and C have differents userId. 
We found an issue when A call B, this call is recieved by B and C.
Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution. WHen logging out you should call the

```
        SinchManager.sharedInstance.sinchClient?.stopListeningOnActiveConnection()
        SinchManager.sharedInstance.sinchClient?.terminateGracefully()
```

Calling terminateGracefully() is not enough. There should be a bug in the iOS SDK

Answer (score 1):

If you are using push you should also unregister push data to avoid this if you are logging in and out of the app.

https://download.sinch.com/docs/iOS/latest/reference/html/Protocols/SINClient.html#//api/name/unregisterPushNotificationData if you roll your own push
and https://download.sinch.com/docs/iOS/latest/reference/html/Protocols/SINClient.html#//api/name/unregisterPushNotificationDeviceToken if you use managed push